# Conceptual limits on mtry in Random Forest algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, accuracy, hyperparameter

I have a random forest being applied to 7 different input variables to predict a particular classification.  I've done a grid search on the hyperparameters `mtry` and `ntree` and it seems as though the algorithm is most accurate when `mtry` is at 6 (the highest value for `mtry` I allowed as a hypothetical value in my search).  This finding has also been confirmed when applied to a test set.  I have an intuition that `mtry` should always be less than the number of total variables in the model but I can't find anything that explicitly states this.

**My question** Is there an upper limit to `mtry` as I think there should be?  And if indeed that's the case, what would it indicate if my model gets more accurate as I approach that upper limit?  Is that something to be concerned about?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`mtry` is indeed bound by the number of variables in your model, as it specifies the size of the variable subset that is randomly picked for each random forest iteration.

Given that it is a hyper-parameter, there is no way to know ahead of time what would be the best value of `mtry`. However, values of mtry that are close to the total number of variables in the model may weaken the forest by making the individual decision trees more correlated; when the decision trees consider similar sets of variables to split on, they are more likely to be similar, even if each is fit to a different bootstrapped data set. Ensemble models usually strive for independence of their members, as that improves predictive ability.

Despite these concerns, the value picked by through proper validation, even if it is large, is probably a fair value to consider for a model.

Comment: See, I was thinking the same thing but when conducting a grid search for a particular set, I found that the best value of `mtry` was 2-3x the number of variables. This was replicated when using caret in r to tune `mtry`.  The efficacy of this hyper-parameter value was confirmed through the use of a test dataset.

Comment: Is this using the `randomForest` package in R? It shouldn't be possible to set `mtry > p`, due to this block of code in the function:
 `p <- ncol(x)` 
...
`if (mtry < 1 || mtry > p) 
        warning("invalid mtry: reset to within valid range")
      mtry <- max(1, min(p, round(mtry)))`

Are you seeing this warning when you have mtry > nVariables?

Comment: Agree with @MirHenglin. It doesn't make sense to take mtry > p [total number of predictors].  As by definition; 'mtry' is the number of variables randomly sampled as candidates at each split

Answer (score 2):

Could the reason for `mtry` being able to exceed `p` be because some of the variables are categorical, and automatically one-hot-encoded into several dummy variables?